# Superset Oauth Integration config using Ambari error

Tags: oauth, apache-superset, ambari, hdp

I am trying to config OAUTH_PROVIDERS using ambari

[image]

```
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/SUPERSET/package/scripts/superset.py", line 184, in <module>
    Superset().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 352, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 971, in restart
    self.stop(env, upgrade_type=upgrade_type)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/SUPERSET/package/scripts/superset.py", line 133, in stop
    self.configure(env, upgrade_type=upgrade_type)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/3.0/services/SUPERSET/package/scripts/superset.py", line 90, in configure
    user=params.superset_user)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/base.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.env.run()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 160, in run
    self.run_action(resource, action)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/environment.py", line 124, in run_action
    provider_action()
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 263, in action_run
    returns=self.resource.returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 72, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 102, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep, timeout_kill_strategy=timeout_kill_strategy, returns=returns)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 150, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/ambari-agent/lib/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 314, in _call
    raise ExecutionFailed(err_msg, code, out, err)
resource_management.core.exceptions.ExecutionFailed: Execution of 'source /usr/hdp/current/superset/conf/superset-env.sh ; /usr/hdp/current/superset/bin/superset db upgrade' returned 1. Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/usr/hdp/current/superset/conf/superset_config.py]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/hdp/current/superset/bin/superset", line 12, in <module>
    from superset.cli import manager
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/superset/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    update_perms=utils.get_update_perms_flag(),
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.init_app(app, session)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/base.py", line 156, in init_app
    self.sm = self.security_manager_class(self)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/sqla/manager.py", line 39, in __init__
    super(SecurityManager, self).__init__(appbuilder)
  File "/usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/manager.py", line 199, in __init__
    provider_name = _provider['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I am able to setup superset Oauth without Ambari, but struggling to make the config in Ambari because even if make change in superset_cofig.py Ambari is overwriting the superset_cofig.py when we restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

I never used Superset with Ambari, but I am currently struggling with it for standalone usage due to the lack of proper documentation and practical use cases.

To my understanding, in order to read the superset_config.py you need to export the PYTHONPATH and point down to the folder where the config is placed.

For example: `export PYTHONPATH=/<folder where the config is placed>/:$PYTHONPATH`

If you get this right, you should see in Superset's logs something like this

```
Loaded your LOCAL configuration at [/<folder where the config is>/superset_config.py]
```